# Make the sum of array values equal to k

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, dart

I came across an algorithmic problem and I can’t figure out how to solve it in principle, because I didn’t find any of the algorithms that could be used here.
Maybe someone can help me with this.

Task:
There is an array of latin characters. Each character in the array can be replaced by any integer number. After the replacement, all identical characters will also be replaced by the same number. Is it possible to make the sum of the array values ​​equal to k?

Input:

1. array - array of latin characters, 0<length(array)<20, sub_array[i]="x" | "y" | "z"
2. k - the value of the sum of the array to be obtained, 0<k<150

Output:
Boolean - you can or cannot make the sum of the values ​​of the array array equal to k

Example (Dart):

```
var array = ["x", "x", "x", "y", "z"];
var k = 10;
print(getResult(array, k)); // return true, because [2, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Can two different characters be associated with the same number?

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed..?

Comment: @damien, no, only positive numbers, and the same character must be tied to the same number.

Comment: @redu, only positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Observation: given `n` x, `m` y, etc, by changing either of x,y,... values by one, the sum can be changed only in GCD(n, m, ...) increments, where GCD is the greatest common divisor (can be found with Euclid algorithm).

Thus, the condition can be satisfied only when `k` is a multiple of their quantities GCD.

Note: this assumes x, y, ... might not be unique, and can be negative

Comment: Hello, can you please explain by an example or with a little bit more detail, why `the sum can be change only in GCD(n, m, ...)`? I'm not challenging your answer, I'm trying to learn and understand. Thank you.

Comment: @user1984 It is basically because all numbers that are multiples of gcd(x, y, z) can be built if x, y and z can be negative, because then you can combine them like you want without overshooting k. gcd(x, y, z) = 1 means they are coprime and all numbers can be built. It is easy to see that if you have 2 even numbers you can never combine them to an odd number and the gcd of 2 even numbers is at least 2.

Comment: @user1984 `m * x + n * y + ... = gcd * (m * x / gcd + n * y / gcd + ...)`. Note that all multiples in the panthesis (`m/gcd, n/gcd, ...`) are coprime integers. This latter fact means the sum of their combination can form any integer; it'll be then multiplied by gcd, allowing to make any multiple of gcd at the end. maraca gave a good intuitive example that no combination of even numbers is odd.

Comment: thank you so much @maraca and Marat this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

First you can go through the array and count the number of occurences of "x", "y" and "z". I will call those counts x, y and z. Then the problem becomes:

Can you find integers a, b and c such that a * x + b * y + c * z = k.

If the numbers can be negative then it is relatively simple: it is possible if k % gcd(x, y, z) = 0 (ignoring 0s, so if x is 0 then k % gcd(y, z) = 0). In other words it is only possible to fail if you can just make multiples of gcd(x, y, z) and k is not a multiple of those numbers.

If a, b and c have to be non-negative, then it becomes a little bit more complex. We are dealing with the coin problem with currencies x, y and z. If k % gcd(x, y, z) != 0 then it is never possible. Now we could simplify the problem by dividing k, x, y and z by gcd(x, y, z). After that we can see if it is easily possible by using the Frobenius numbers:

n = 2: all numbers > x * y - x - y can be built

n = 3: all numbers > sqrt(3 * x * y * z) can be built

If k is smaller than that we can check if k can be built by using the common dynamic programming solution for the coin problem.

Of course there are some edge cases you have to deal with. E.g. k = 0 or if there is only one number given, then it is just k % x = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that works on the assumptions that:

- a number can be assigned to at most one character
- there is at least one character that occurs only once

```js
function findNumbers([s,sum]) {   // count occurences of characters:
  let ar1 = Object.entries(s.split("").reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a), {}))
   .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]); // sort: most frequent characters first
  
  // assign interger values to each character (starting with 1 ...
  let ar2=ar1.map(([c, n], i) =>{ // c: character, n: occurences, i: index
    sum-=n*(i+1);
    return [c, i+1<ar1.length? i+1: ar1.length+sum]
   });
  return [Object.fromEntries(ar2),ar2.pop()[1]>ar2.pop()[1]]; // add a results flag to each solution: true/false
}

let res=[["xxxyz",10],["ghijjk",17],["abcabcabd",12],["abccdef",18],["abcd",9]].map(findNumbers)

console.log(res)  // true, true, false, false, false
```

Obviously this was a fast shot. I do not yet check whether the least frequent character only occurs once. It certainly needs more refinement but it indicates already pretty quickly whether a solution with positive integers would be possible. If the last number is not greater then the penultimate one, suitable numbers cannot be found and the `false` flag is returned.

Comment: You also assume that negative integers are allowed however expected boolean result implies that there should be a `false` case. I think using negatives wouldn't allow a `false` result.

Comment: @Redu: That can be assessed very easily: just treat each result with a negative number as "false" (=solution not possible)

Comment: As you might have already guessed there is also the `0` case.

Comment: The "0-case" is already tested as "false" (like negative). I was negligent in my comment and didn't formulate it sufficiently clear. But the code works OK: `ar2.pop()[1]>ar2.pop()[1]`. The test actually ascertains whether the last number is larger than the previous one.

Comment: There are problems in this code...  Please test  `findNumbers(["abcd",9]);`.

Comment: `["abcd",9]` results in `false`. Where is the problem?

Comment: Such a solution is indeed simpler, but does not satisfy the conditions: there can be several characters in a line, and a number is assigned to the character. In these conditions, the whole difficulty lies ....
Only positive numbers, and the same character must be tied to the same number.

Comment: My algorithm does indeed only accept positive numbers, otherwise `false` will be returned. The only limitation it has is that there must be at least *one* character that occurs *only once*, otherwise all other conditions of your questions are matched.